# Plotting line in linechart according to specific math formula

Tags: highcharts

I have a slightly complicated problem with my line chart.

I manage to make dynamic line chart, so when the user will input some points, they will be drawn on the graph as a line.

Now, my problem here is to add the second line on the graph automatically, according to the inputted values and specific formula that will calculate the second values for the second line.

Let me illustrate what I mean… First it’s drawn one  line based on the previously inputted values. Let’s say, user input these values 1.6, 3.9, 3.3, 4.0, 2.5, 2.8…

===============================

The second line needs to be drawn according to this formula, that will loop through the inputted values...

```
var interestRate1 = 3.5 + inputed_value1 + 0.5 * (inputed_value1 - 3),
        interestRate2 = 3.5 + inputed_value2 + 0.5 * (inputed_value2 - 3),
        interestRate2 = 3.5 + inputed_value3 + 0.5 * (inputed_value3 - 3), etc…
```

Eventually the formula will calculate my second values (4.4, 7.85, 6.95, 8, 5.75, 6.2) and this is the outcome that I want to be achieved…

http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/9606/0sfy.png

===============================

On clicking the button “Draw the graph” it needs to be drawn 2 lines, one that is originally inputted from the user, and the second that is calculated by my formula.

Refer to my code here

> http://jsfiddle.net/97SRR/4/

(I don’t know why the graph in not showing, it was fine on my index.html file…)

Please help me with this, I will appreciate any ideas about my code.. I have been struggling with this for weeks :(

Comment: The chart does not show on jsFiddle because you did not include a framwork (jQuery or equivalent) and you did not include the reference to the highchart library. Even with those enabled it still fails because `getParams` is not defined. Does your formula spit out x/y pairs?

Comment: Yes Sir, I see the problem with jsFiddle, but that is not my biggest concern right now... My formula is only for economical/mathematical purpose, it doesn't split anything. That is what I am trying to do with my js code, plotting the first values that are inputted by the user, and plotting the second ones based on my mathematical formula. It cannot be that difficult, but I have no idea how to implement that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is where you create series:

```
var sample = {};
sample.name = 'Inflation';
sample.data = [1.6, 3.9, 3.3, 4.0, 2.5, 2.8];

series.push(sample);
```

So you need just to add one more series, for example:

```
function calc(data) { 
  var l = data.length,
      ret = []; 

  for(var i = 0; i < l; i++) { 
    ret[i] = 3.5 + data[i] + 0.5 * (data[i] - 3);
  } 
  return ret; 
}
var sample = {};
sample.name = 'Inflation';
sample.data = [1.6, 3.9, 3.3, 4.0, 2.5, 2.8];

series.push(sample);

var calculated = {};
calculated.name = 'Math formula';
calculated.data = calc(sample.data); // [4.4, 7.85, 6.95, 8, 5.75, 6.2]; - calculated data

series.push(calculated);
```

Comment: That was very helpful Sir, I would like to honestly thank you for your effort! But there still remains one little problem...
In my formula: 

var data = 3.5 + inputted_value1 + 0.5 * (inputed_value1 - 3)

...The "inputted_value1" is a variable, so my question is, how can I make calculation on those variables, or how can I access one specific element from my sample.data let's say?

For example here are my series:
sample.data = [1.6, 3.9, 3.3, 4.0, 2.5, 2.8];
And how can I access the first element 1.6, considered as a variable? Is there some method?

Comment: I think you should consider or reading some javascript tutorials, or hiring some web-developer ;) It's really basic knowledge of javascript. See my updated answer.

Comment: Oh, look at that, this is awesome :) My problem is almost done... Now this is my final question, I am not bothering you anymore.
In this line --> calculated.data = calc(sample.data); You are taking the sample data that is statically predefined previously and make calculations. Now I want to take as parameter for my function "calc" the values that are inputted dynamically by the user, and then make calculation on them. Is that possible? I did consider learning javascript but these things seem so confusing for me, and I am so desperate to finish my project :(

Comment: It's possible, read about jQuery and especially about `val()` function. Description is [here](http://api.jquery.com/val/). PS: Don't forget to accept answer ;)